# Execute POL shortcut directly without invoking POL itself

Tags: wine, playonlinux

How can I execute the target of a PlayOnLinux shortcut directly (with the correct wine version) without actually invoking PlayOnLinux?

My problem is, that I need to run the shortcut in a headless docker container.

POL requires X to be present so I could circumvent this by using:

```
xvfb-run playonlinux-bash ./path/to/shortcut
```

But I'm not very happy with this solution as it rarely shuts down cleanly ... resulting in error messages ... so I always have to look twice if everything worked or if it actually crashed.

For clarification, assuming we have a POL shortcut like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env playonlinux-bash
[ "$PLAYONLINUX" = "" ] && exit 0                             <- not needed
source "$PLAYONLINUX/lib/sources"                             <- works without POL
export WINEPREFIX="/home/test/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/test"   <- works without POL
export WINEDEBUG=""                                           <- works without POL
cd "/home/test/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/test/drive_c"          <- works without POL
POL_Wine text.exe "$@"                                        <- how do I do this 
                                                                 in a normal bash 
                                                                 without POL, using 
                                                                 the wine version 
                                                                 from POL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While still having to call `POL_Wine` I managed to get rid of the X dependency:

After diving into the POL source code (and realizing that most of it is just a bunch of bash code) 
I came up with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash 

# provide environment variables normally set by playonlinux-bash
PLAYONLINUX="/usr/share/playonlinux"
POL_USER_ROOT="/home/gamer/.PlayOnLinux"
POL_OS="Linux"
export WINEPREFIX="$POL_USER_ROOT/wineprefix/test"
export WINEDEBUG=""

# load POL functions without having to go through playonlinux-bash
source "$PLAYONLINUX/lib/sources"

# mock error reporting to prevent opening of error-windows
POL_Debug_Error() 
{
    echo "[POL] $1"
}

POL_Debug_Message() 
{
    echo "[POL] $1"
}

# finally start the target executable
cd "$WINEPREFIX/drive_c"    
POL_Wine test.exe "$@"
```